# Помогите ускорить программу

Tags: python, python-3.x

Делители факториала
По заданному натуральному числу N необходимо вычислить количество натуральных чисел, которые есть делителями N! (факториала числа N).

Например, при N=4, N!=4⋅3⋅2⋅1=24. Это число имеет следующие делители: 1,2,3,4,6,8,12,24. Таким образом, искомое количество составляет 8.

Напишите программу, которая по натуральному N, находит количество делителей его факториала.

Формат входных данных

Единственная строка входного файла содержит одно целое число N(1≤N≤45).

Формат выходных данных

Единственная строка выходного файла должна содержать одно целое число — найденное количество делителей числа N!
Примеры:
Ввод 4
Вывод 8
     Пишет, что программа выполняется слишком долго. Bот мой код:

```
x = int(input())
n = 1
while x > 0:
    n *= x
    x -= 1
a = []
k = 1
s = 0
while k * k <= n:
    if n % k == 0:
        a.append(k)
        if n // k != k:
            a.append(n // k)
    k += 1
print(len(a))
```

Comment: Нужно просто перемножить числа от 1 до N во всех комбинациях, и посчитать количество разных результатов,  а не делать перебор на 100500 чисел.

Comment: В 30! больше 30 знаков. Если перебором считать, то до пенсии вряд ли успеешь.

Comment: используйте c++

Comment: @VladislavTikhomirov сколько займёт перебор 10^30 чисел?

Comment: Следует получить разложение факториала на простые множители, после чего посчитать произведение инкрементированных количеств. Для показанного примера *Например, при N=4, N!=4⋅3⋅2⋅1=24* - `4! = 2^3 * 3^1`, соответственно ответ `(3+1)*(1+1)=4*2=8`.

Comment: @Эникейщик *Нужно просто перемножить числа от 1 до N во всех комбинациях* Это бессмысленно. Например, 6! делится на 9, но никакое произведение чисел от 1 до 6 этого делителя не даст.

Comment: @Akina да, верно. Я думал, так можно избежать разложения на простые множители.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())
x=1
for i in range(n):
    x=x*i
a=[]
z=0
for j in range(x):
    if x%j==0:
        a[z]=j
        z+=1
print(*a)
```

Я не ускорил твой код, но написал свой, надеюсь он вписывается по времени.